# The following StackOverflowError was thrown building _BodyBuilder: Stack Overflow after Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After firebase upgrade I can see firebase-core is mandatory , so I have modified my code accordingly but don't have idea about initializeApp function, So I have searched over the internet regarding this and added this line `await Firebase.initializeApp();` but now I am getting this error

```
W/DynamiteModule(20840): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(20840): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(20840): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(20840): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///Users/masummolla/FlutterProjects/admin/lib/screens/active_user.dart:32:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase.== (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:280:7)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin._getValueOrData (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:670:10695)
#2      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:129:7844)
#3      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:8:27)
#4      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:8:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///Users/masummolla/FlutterProjects/admin/lib/screens/active_user.dart:32:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase.== (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:280:7)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin._getValueOrData (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:670:10695)
#2      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:129:7844)
#3      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:8:27)
#4      new FirestoreService (package:admin/services/firestore_service.dart:8:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I don't know the exact reason

here is my codes in main.dart file

```
import 'package:admin/models/route_generator.dart';
import 'package:admin/user_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await UserPreferences().init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,

        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: '/',


    );
  }
}
```

and here is the code for active_user.dart file

```
import 'package:admin/screens/class_videos.dart';
import 'package:admin/screens/important_videos.dart';
import 'package:admin/screens/live_class.dart';
import 'package:admin/screens/user_details.dart';
import 'package:admin/screens/weekly_updates.dart';
import 'package:admin/user_preferences.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ActiveUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ActiveUserState createState() => _ActiveUserState();
}

class _ActiveUserState extends State<ActiveUser> {

  int landing = 2;
  int _page = 2;
  @override
  void initState(){
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    super.initState();
    landing = UserPreferences().landing;
    _page=landing;
  }

  final pageScreen = [ImportantVideos(),WeeklyUpdates(),ClassVideos(),LiveClass(),UserDetails()];
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Badshai Trading Videos'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: _page==landing ? Icon(Icons.touch_app,color: Colors.white,) :Icon(Icons.pan_tool,color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_page!=landing){
                UserPreferences().landing=_page;
                setState(() {
                  landing=_page;
                });
              }else if(_page==landing && _page!=2){
                setState(() {
                  landing = 2;
                  UserPreferences().landing=landing;
                });

              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: pageScreen[_page],
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        index: _page,
        height: 50.0,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.important_devices, size: 20,color: _page==0 ?Colors.amber:Colors.black,),
          Icon(Icons.multiline_chart, size: 20,color: _page==1 ?Colors.amber:Colors.black,),
          Icon(Icons.live_tv, size: 20,color: _page==2 ?Colors.amber:Colors.black,),
          Icon(Icons.card_membership, size: 20,color: _page==3 ?Colors.amber:Colors.black,),
          Icon(Icons.more, size: 20,color: _page==4 ?Colors.amber:Colors.black,),
        ],
        color: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _page = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anybody can help me out of this stack I will be thankful to them

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got the bugs had used `FirestoreService _ndb = FirestoreService();` this line in my FirestoreService class, just commented it